# Must be one of: View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE

Tags: android, android-view

I am saving and restoring a views visibility in one of my activities. I do this by calling `mButton.getVisibility()` and saving this in a `Bundle`. In onRestore where I get the int value it is showing an error.

```
Must be one of: View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.GONE less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Reports two types of problems:
- Supplying the wrong type of resource identifier. For example, when calling Resources.getString(int id), you should be passing R.string.something, not R.drawable.something.
- Passing the wrong constant to a method which expects one of a specific set of constants. For example, when calling View#setLayoutDirection, the parameter must be android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR or android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL.
```

The code compiles and runs with no errors

**code**

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt("BUTTON_VISIBILITY", mButton.getVisibility());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    mButton.setVisibility(savedInstanceState.getInt("BUTTON_VISIBILITY"));
    // savedInstanceState.getInt("BUTTON_VISIBILITY") is underlined red
}
```

Comment: You can add `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")`

Comment: Normally a warning is underlined yellow, this is underlined red causing me some concern

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType") worked! thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I have just commented, you can add `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")`. Hope this helps!

Alt-Enter
[image]

Comment: Yes this did the job, thank you

Comment: My experience is that: when AS warns, press Alt-Enter to find a solution :)

Comment: Alt-Enter didnt have anything for this :/

Comment: can you upvote the question if you think it might help somebody someday? cheers

Comment: Yes, and I add a picture for Alt-Enter :)

Comment: ah, that is useful thank you

Comment: You should choose _"Suppress for statement"_ which yields an _"//noinspection ..."_ comment above that statement.

Comment: @SupressWarning is not  solving the issue, It will not show that type of error further thats all. Please find the solution,